# Changing global font size to 11.5 pts

Tags: fonts, fontspec, windows, article

I'd like to set the main font in my document to 11.5 points. I realize this is not possible using one of the preset options for the `article` document class, so I tried to follow the instructions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473838/how-to-set-the-font-size-to-11-5pt/473839). Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\fontsize{13pt}{13pt}\selectfont

\begin{document}
  \blindtext
\end{document}
```

However, setting the fontsize as shown does not change the size for my main font.

How can I get my main, default font to be 11.5 points?

Comment: the fontsize you show selects 13pt but begin document does \normalsize so you do not see any text at 13pt. You could use that within the document though.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `fontsize` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[fontsize=11.5bp]{fontsize}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
  \blindtext
\end{document}
```

The (uncompressed) PDF file has

```
%PDF-1.5
%<E4><F0><ED><F8>
6 0 obj
<</Length 3622>>
stream
 q 1 0 0 1 72 769.89 cm 0 G 0 g 0 g 0 G BT /F1 11.5 Tf 63.078 -65.753 Td[...
```

Comment: How do I install `fontsize` package on Ubuntu? It says `file 'fontsize.sty' not found`...

Comment: @user32882 You need an up-to-date TeX Live. Ubuntu installs an older one, you can install the “vanilla” TeX Live, see http://tug.org/texlive

Answer (score 4):

You can copy the definition of `\normalsize` from the class and change (I assume you want 11.5bp here)

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
%   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xipt{13.6}%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize{11.5bp}{13.6}% I assume you want 11.5 postscript points 
   \abovedisplayskip 11\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus6\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6.5\p@ \@plus3.5\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
\normalsize
    \MakeRobust\normalsize
\let\@normalsize\normalsize
\makeatother

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}


\begin{document}
\showthe\font
  \blindtext
\end{document}
```

This produces

```
> \TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n/11.54312 .
```

instead of the original

```
> \TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n/10.95 .
```

Comment: or you could use 12pt option with no change which makes `> \TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n/12 .`   the difference is less than  .46pt  which really isn't very much.